# Alpha testing in Google play and Authentication problems

Tags: android, google-play-services, in-app-billing

I upload an app in Alpha testing for testing In app Billing, and I notice there is a button up to the right called Publish App, this means to publish my app in Production or to Alpha level?

Is this the reason why I get a message that says I need authentication to Google Play, when I click the Subscription button?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what tab you chose in the APK setup, if it's Production, Beta or Alpha. Follow this [guide](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/1287/how-to-upload-and-download-an-alpha-or-beta-app-to-google-play) on *How to upload and download an Alpha or Beta app to Google Play*:

1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, click APK > Beta Testing or Alpha Testing.
4. Click Upload.
5. Select your APK file.
6. Click Publish.

For the error ***Need authentication to Google Play***:

As indicated in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeakFdvDFtI), go to Google Play in your Applicaton Settings and click the **CLEAR DATA** button. Check this documentation about [How to fix ''Google Play authentication is required'' error](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-fix-google-play-authentication-is-required-error).

Answer (score 0):

> this means to publish my app in Production or to Alpha level?

When you upload to Alpha channel it gets published to alpha channel. You can later move the published apk to beta channel or production (if you want).

> Is this the reason why I get a message that says I need authentication
>   to Google Play, when I click the Subscription button?

No, Which channel you upload to has nothing to do with the functionality. It is just to make the app available to specific set of people. Production channel will make it available for download to general public, where as the alpha and beta channel will make it available for download only to the users you'll add as testers for each channel. This is definitely not a reason that would impact functionality.

The authentication error must be a result of a problem either in your code or device. It has nothing to do with what channel you publish your app on